# Get md5sum without file name?

Tags: unix, md5

I need to get the md5 sum of a file on AIX, but the `md5sum` program prints the sum followed by the name of the file.

How can I get the sum *without the file name*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
md5sum < filename
```

This will give you an empty filename.

Comment: That outputs a `-` to represent stdin.

Comment: This is what i use.  Don't need `cat` though, just redirect
`md5sum < filename`

Comment: Good point @Rich, I do like that better

Answer (score 13):

```
md5sum filename | awk '{print $1}'
```

That would be one way.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, just was not sure how he was getting the md5 in the first place.

Comment: @Chris I figured this was the way as he mentioned the md5sum program.

Comment: This will remove the "-" from the md5sum < filename

Answer (score 5):

Also:

```
md5sum filename | cut -c -32
```

Which has the benefit of having no quotes or characters needing to be escaped, in case you need to embed that command someplace which might have multiple string interpreters acting on it.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to do :

```
md5sum filename |cut -f 1 -d " "
```

Cut will split line to each space and return only first field.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to assign the output to an array as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5773761/111036):

```sh
md5=( $(md5sum "filename") )
echo $md5
```

Another way is to strip the space and anything after it:

```sh
md5=$(md5sum "filename")
echo ${md5/ *}
```